# Does a disabled extension keep its permissions on google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, permissions, google-chrome-extensions

For example, would an extension that has the two permissions:

- Read and change all your data on the websites you visit
- Read data you copy and paste

that was installed and disabled on Chrome still be able to read data you copy and paste, and still be able to read and change all your data on the websites you visit?

Answer (score 0):

Disabled extensions keep their permissions but are not allowed to act on them. This means when you enable it again you will not be prompted to allow the extension access again unless the extension was updated and is requesting new permissions other than those already granted previously.

Disabled extensions retain permissions but a disabled extension cannot act on those permissions. Enabling the extension will remember the allowed permissions, allowing the extension to act upon them.